# Pandas inner merge/join returning all rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge, inner-join

I'm trying to merge two data frames based on a column present in both, keeping only the intersection of the two sets.

The desired result is:

```
 foo           bar            foobar
x y z        x j i           x y z j i
a 1 2        a 9 0           a 1 2 9 0
b 3 4        b 9 0           b 3 4 9 0 
c 5 6        c 9 0           c 5 6 9 0
d 7 8        e 9 0           
             f 9 0
```

My code that does not produce the desired result is:

```
pd.merge(foo, bar, how='inner', on='x')
```

Instead, the code seems to return:

```
 foo           bar            foobar
x y z        x j i           x y z j i
a 1 2        a 9 0           a 1 2 9 0
b 3 4        b 9 0           b 3 4 9 0 
c 5 6        c 9 0           c 5 6 9 0
d 7 8        e 9 0           e * * 9 0
             f 9 0           f * * 9 0
```

(where * represents an NaN)

Where am I going wrong? I've already reached the third Google page trying to fix this an nothing works. Whatever I do I get an outer join, with all rows in both sets.

Comment: what result does your code give ?

Comment: @MaxU What I don't understand is that this code does indeed give the correct result.

Comment: @MaxU They are slightly different although they represent the same thing - one is a non-null int64 while the other is int64. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, i think it's because of duplicates in the `x` column

Comment: @MaxU You mean in OP's actual data?

Comment: @mannaroth, do you have duplicates in the "joining" column - `x` in your sample DFs?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, yep

Comment: @MaxU - no, all items in the joining column 'x' are unique. I'm puzzled by this behavior, it should definitely work and yet it does not.

Comment: @mannaroth, can you try to post __reproducible__ sample data sets?

Comment: @MaxU I have a few million rows in total. How can I provide such an example?

Comment: @mannaroth, can you post an output of: `print(foo.shape, foo['x'].nunique()); print(bar.shape, bar['x'].nunique())`?

Comment: @MaxU (307677, 8) 307677   (5862863, 6) 306106

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150880/discussion-between-mannaroth-and-maxu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it means that you have duplicates in the column(s) used for joining, resulting in cartesian product.

Demo:

```
In [35]: foo
Out[35]:
   x  y  z
0  a  1  2
1  b  3  4
2  c  5  6
3  d  7  8

In [36]: bar
Out[36]:
   x  j  i
0  a  9  0
1  b  9  0
2  a  9  0
3  a  9  0
4  b  9  0

In [37]: pd.merge(foo, bar)
Out[37]:
   x  y  z  j  i
0  a  1  2  9  0
1  a  1  2  9  0
2  a  1  2  9  0
3  b  3  4  9  0
4  b  3  4  9  0
```